# ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator

Tags: soql, attachment, contentdocument

I am trying to get list of all the ContentDocumentLink which are not available in a set. But when I try to get `NOT IN` its giving error `Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.` But when I remove NOT form the query it is working. I tried the same `NOT IN` for attachment SOQL here it works perfectly. Do anyone have any idea why this is not working with NOT IN condition in SOQL.

Attachment Code

```
attLst = [SELECT Id, Name, body, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ID NOT IN : transfer.keyset()];
```

ContentDocumentLink Code

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contDoc = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    Map<String, Transfer__c> transfer = new Map<String, Transfer__c>();
    for(Transfer__c trans : [SELECT File_Attachment__c, Transfered__c FROM Transfer__c WHERE Transfered__c = true ]){
        transfer.put(trans.File_Attachment__c, trans);
    }
    
    contDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId NOT IN : transfer.keyset() ];
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation restriction on Content objects. You simply can't run unrestricted or negative queries against `ContentDocumentLink`. You *must* query that object using an `=` or `IN` clause, as the error message specifies.

You'll probably need to rethink your logic to work in terms of [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) instead, and you may need to consider running the automation in the context of a user who has Query All Files permission if you need to be able to query every Content record in your org. Once you acquire `ContentDocument` Ids, you can query `ContentDocumentLink` records if you still need to.